# Resharper create property with backing field

Tags: resharper

How do you create property with a backing field in Resharper?

This is the first thing you would want to do with a class and I cannot find how to it.

Its so simple.

Answer (score 13):

Within the body of the `class`, type `prop` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Supply the property's type and name. This will create an autoproperty (these days, it is typically one of these you would want to create).

Then, with the cursor on the property name, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and choose `To property with backing field`.

Answer (score 7):

The quickest way I've found is to type your property as if it exists already:

```
this.MyProperty = "hello";
```

Then Alt-Return on the property name, and choose Create Property 'MyProperty' then hit tab to choose between auto-property, managed backing field, or default member body.

I believe this is quicker than using the `prop` shortcut, hitting tab, specifying the property type, hitting tab twice, specifying the name, and then pressing Alt-Return on the property name and choosing the 'to property with backing field' selection.

You could also create a Live Template so that there is slightly less work, e.g:

```
/// <summary>
/// Private backing field for $Property$ property
/// </summary>
private $Type$ $BackingField$;

public $Type$ $Property$
{
    get
    {
        return this.$BackingField$;
    }

    set
    {
        this.$BackingField$ = value;     
    }
}
```

The parameter $BackingField$ can be generated automatically from $Property$ by the "first character in lower case" macro of the template editor and setting it to "Not editable".

But I believe the first method is the quickest and easiest.

Comment: I cant believe you cant do it from in the class, Im in shock...this 101 stuff. Must be amateurs at resharper.

Comment: Im glad I got a trial version

Comment: I think this is actually quicker, as R# can infer the property type from the assignment. However, you could also create a Live Template. I've updated the answer to include an example.

Comment: I couldn't do without R#. Also, get StyleCop which includes StyleCop for R#.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a property with a getter and setter, sometimes you will find that the backing field you used is no longer available because you changed the base class for the current class or you made other changes. For example, in the `LinesMax` property below, the backing field `Height` is available from an inherited class:

```
public int LinesMax
{
   get { return ConvertValGet(AdjustMetricEnum.Height, Height); }
   set { Height = ConvertValSet(AdjustMetricEnum.Height, value); }
}
```

If the above code works but I decide afterwards no longer to inherit the class that exposes the Height property, the two Height variable names will turn red in the IDE to indicate that they're no longer available to the code.

At that point, I may want to create a private backing field. To easily create that, I can first modify the Height name to _height, then place the cursor on either _height name, hit Alt-Enter then choose Create field '_height'. A backing field will be created.